# Razor dynamic compilation of view files

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I have an console application targeting **.NET 4.7.2** with SDK **Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web** and using **MVC Core 2.2**.
What i want to achieve is to have the views to be precompiled BUT with an ability to override them with custom cshtml files when required.

As i understand in order to be able to achieve that i will need to have **PreserveCompilationContext** to be set to true in my project file.
Also in order to have compilation dependencies (ref folder) to be generated on publish i will need to have **CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory** set to true.
This will cause an ref folder to be generated with required compilation dependencies and the **deps.json** configuration file.

So my questions are

1. For the deployment i will need to include both deps.json and refs folder along with my application, based on my observation if those are not included and cshtml file is present in views directory compilation fails.
2. Is there a way to generate compilation dependencies on build instead of publish ?
3. Is there anything i should be aware of in terms of how this could affect precompiled views rendering?

In general i am just trying to figure if i am making correct steps to achieve the desired behaviour.

Thanks!

Comment: `What i want to achieve is to have the views to be precompiled BUT with an ability to override them with custom cshtml files when required.` Can you clarify more about it?

Comment: Sure, so we have the precompiled views that are generated by Razor into a dll, so far so good. In some case we want to allow users to override the Views present in the precompiled dll with their own. For example there is an precompiled view named Home.cshtml, if the view file is present in the Views directory the that view should be used instead of precompiled one. As i said everything works as intended and i just want to know if i am not missing something that could cause troubles.